# Prevent reloading on every Angular Route Change

Tags: templates, angularjs, caching, grid

using angular:

I have a jquery grid control on index page, every time user changes view (add, edit, details) and comes back to index it will be recreate. how index page can be cached with rendered jquery grid?

Comment: You can put the jQuery grid outside of the `ng-view` Angular routes only change what is in the `ng-view` of course this would probably mean creating an additional controller and communications glue between other controllers if necessary.  You can signal the grid's controller to hide it on different routes.

Comment: I have a main.html page (ng-view here), and partial views including _categories.html (grid in this page) , _add and _edit for catergories.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener on the scope whenever the route is about to change and evaluate if it should be changed or not:

Example:

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  if (itShouldNotReload) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: I think they just don't want the grid to reload, not stop the route change.

Comment: yes I just don't want the grid to reload, not stop the route change.